# Can't get more than two sections objects in tableview

Tags: swift, tableview

I wanna learn about sections in tableview. Ive been following Jared Davidson youtube tutorial. But i can only add two strings into the objects below the section title. Its like theres somekind of limit?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the future, please copy your code into your question as text, not screen shots. It is easier for us to help you when we can copy the code out to paste into a test project or playground or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`, you need to return the number of rows in the section. Right now you're returning the number of sections (which is what you should, and do, return from `numberOfSectionsInTableView(_:)`).

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because in your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` delegate functions you get the count of the Objects array which only has two objects in it. Your sections is the object count but your rows are sectionsObject array you are putting in each object in the objects array.